# can we set ImageUrl to physical path?

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

I have a `image control` and I have to set it's `ImageUrl` to a `physical path` like `C:\image\image1.jpg` but control takes virtual path only. How to show that image if path we have is physical path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No because the client (browser) can't access that file. It needs to be a file that is exposed to "the internet". You will need to move the image elsewhere and reference it with the tilde `~` which means "application path": `~/Images/images1.jpg`.

Comment: You could also write an .ASHX handler to stream the file to the browser.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a [Virtual Folder in IIS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771804%28v=ws.10%29.aspx). You can then set your image control's path to be that of the Virtual Folder.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, the image has to be in the web root for the end user to see it and it therefore will have a virtual path.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `Proxy Object`. This object should load the image from physical path as an server it when the page needs it. It can be as simple as loading it to a static variable or a complex Lazy (load image on demand) proxy with file system watcher for tracking changes of images.

It could be a control or web-service (maybe authentication is needed).

Answer (score 0):

Still the image has to be placed in local server root folder. Not a physical path.

Answer (score 0):

No. We, as software developers, do not directly interact with the physical layer. The physical layer is (usually) magnetic particles on a spinning platter. There is no physical path to it. We operate at several layers of abstraction above the physical layer.